# How to test django (3.0) CreateView's 'form_valid' method and parameters with a test client?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-testing

### Some info

I'm overriding the `form_valid` method (for one reason or another).

### What I'm trying to do

I want to test the `form_valid` instance, and specifically its arguments. To do so, I'm using [Django's test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client).

### Some code

`models.py`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_model_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    my_model_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'my model date',
        auto_now_add=True)
```

`views.py`:

```
class CreateMyModelView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.edit.CreateView):

    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'myapp/create-my-model.html'
    form_class = CreateMyModelForm

    def post(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):

        # do something here
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, request)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form, request):

        # do something else here
        my_model_text = form.cleaned_data['my_model_text']
        MyModel.objects.create(my_model_text=my_model_text)

        return redirect(reverse('myapp:mypage'))
```

`forms.py`:

```
class CreateMyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['my_model_text']
```

`tests.py`:

```
class CreateMyModelViewTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):

        cls.my_auth_user = User.objects.create(
            username='my_auth_user')
        cls.my_auth_user.set_password('my_auth_password')
        cls.my_auth_user.save()

    def test_form_valid(self):

        client = self.client
        client.login(
            username='my_auth_user',
            password='my_auth_password')
        # post response ? #
```

### Question

How can I test the arguments that `form_valid` gets with the test-client (not an instance of the `form` object, but the `form_valid` method itself)?

Comment: None of the code you've posted seems to mention `session`... Surely you know `request.user` will hold a reference to the currently logged in user, if that's the information you're storing?

Answer (score 0):

Since CBVs store the current request as `self.request`, you don't need to change the signature of `form_valid`.

I think your view can/should be simplified to something like this (and as you can see, there's just commented-out stuff in `form_valid()` too, so you can elide it entirely unless you need to modify the instance using e.g. the request user).

```
class CreateMyModelView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'myapp/create-my-model.html'
    form_class = CreateMyModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:mypage')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # You can modify the object-to-be-saved before saving, e.g.
        # form.instance.creator = self.request.user

        # The CreateView implementation just calls `form.save()` and redirects away,
        # so let's reuse that.
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Hi @AKX Thanks so much for your answer :) (1) Since I posted this I changed my design and, as you've suggested, now form_valid() is not overridden. (2) Regarding your comment - I wasn't trying to get user information, I was trying to save 'an environment state' for the user. (3) My question does not concern the form_valid() use, it concerns testing (testing any method which I decide to override, using the test client). So, let's assume I decide to override some method - is the only way to test its arguments would be to also override the method which calls it?

Comment: My apologies @AKX, you're totally right, I forgot to update this question, and the reason why I left the post this way. I cleared all the mess, and I hope it's better phrased now.

Comment: You can certainly initialize a `CreateMyModelView` object and call the instance's `form_valid` (the Django `RequestFactory` object may come in handy), but I'm not quite sure why you'd need to test that c.f. testing that the view does what it needs to when posted some given data.

Comment: For debugging purposes. But I guess this discussion has been rendered pointless without some concrete example (and a well-excused one at that)... So until I'll run into a specific case - I'll just thank you for your time, and your answers :) thanks